# Renaming a file in as3 AIR - how to do it if you have file's native path in a var?

Tags: air, file-rename

The following code is great for renaming a file if you know the file is in applicationStorageDirectory

```
var sourceFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
sourceFile = sourceFile.resolvePath("Kalimba.snd");
var destination:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
destination = destination.resolvePath("test.snd");

try  
{
    sourceFile.moveTo(destination, true);
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Error:" + error.message);
}
```

How do you set the sourceFile if all you have is the file's native path in a string? Like this:

```
D:\Software\files\testList.db
```

This throws errors:

```
sourceFile = sourceFile.resolvePath("D:\Software\files\testList.db");
```

The idea is I want to rename a file I had previously loaded into a var. I figured I'd extract the native path to a String var, null the File var (so the OS doesn't tell me it can't be renamed while the file is opened in flash), resolve that nativePath as the sourceFile, and use moveTo to rename the file on the hard drive.

Cheers for taking a look.

EDIT:

I've set up a test AIR app with only the following in it:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;

var original = File.documentsDirectory; 
original = original.resolvePath("D:\\Software\\test\\October.db"); 

var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory; 
destination =  destination.resolvePath("copy.db"); 

original.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileMoveCompleteHandler); 
original.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, fileMoveIOErrorEventHandler); 
original.moveToAsync(destination); 

function fileMoveCompleteHandler(event:Event):void { 
    trace(event.target); // [object File] 
} 
function fileMoveIOErrorEventHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void { 
    trace("I/O Error.");  
}
```

This fails, as does using D:\Software\test\October.db

I guess what I want to know it - how do you do the resolvePath thing if you already know the full path?

Comment: So you already have a `File` class instance linked to the file you want to rename? It should be no problem to use this for renaming, a file is not "in use" until you actually open it (for example using a stream).

Comment: That's what I thought. However, moveTo fails, although copyTo succeeds.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is actually locked? Maybe you just don't have write permission for that specific file/folder? also what does the exact code look like where the problem occours? And what error exactly do you receive? For the sake of completeness (not sure whether it's just a copy & paste mistake), in string literals backslashes must be escaped in order to act as backslashes, ie your path should be like `D:\\Software\\files\\testList.db`.

Comment: I've set up a test AIR app that has exactly this:

Comment: Ignore that last comment - I edited my original question with all the code from a test AIR app. THANKS!

Comment: OK - I think I got it. If you know the path of a file the user saved anywhere, use userDirectory as in var original = File.userDirectory; original = original.resolvePath(path); var destination:File = File.userDirectory; destination =  destination.resolvePath("D:/wherever_you_want_it/renamedFile.db");   Also, I found I had to make the backward slashes forward ones.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, you should be able to resolve an absolute path from any file object whatsoever, the original path should only matter when resolving relative paths. Though looking at your code it's not necessary to use `resolvePath()`, you can just pass the absolute path to the [**`File` constructor**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#File()) instead, besides your code snippet works fine for me as is. btw, if you are experiencing an I/O Error, then you should trace the actual error, ie `trace(event)`.

Comment: Thanks ndm, and great tip about tracing the Error! I figured it out - I was passing the rename job to a class I made to handle fixing flawed SQL database schemas. I was using asynchronous functions, waiting for an event listener to fire before returning back to my main code. However, the code returns before the listener fires. ie the main code was trying to create a new db named the same as the old one, before the old one had a chance to be renamed. So I set it up synchronous instead, and now there's no IO error.

Answer (score 0):

> > I guess what I want to know it - how do you do the resolvePath thing if you already know the full path?

You don't AFAIK. If your path is actually d:\software\test\october.db you can set a File ref like:

```
var original:File = new File();
original.nativePath = "d:\software\test\october.db";
```